# copy all constraints from one DB to another DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

can you please assist to 
My test env is not in sync in regards of table constrainst - I would like to copy all constraint types from one DB to another DB.

Comment: One thing we do, which we've had a lot of success with is taking a backup of production and doing a restore to development or test.  One It makes a realistic view of production for development, two we can debug specific production issues when things break but only for one specific record, and three we test that the backup and restore is always in working order.

Comment: You should use a proper change/schema management tool to put your changes into production. That way you wouldn't need such a workaround.

Comment: i can't delete any data of my test env and need to sync with prod env with regards to all table constraints- is it possible to get data from dba_constraint and run in my test env?